# How do I programmatically set-up storage account access keys for auto rotation in key vault?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-keyvault

I intend to accomplish the following:

1. create a storage account
2. create a key vault
3. add the storage account to the key vault aka add access keys to vault
4. set-up storage access keys for auto rotation

I am developing in C# and have managed to accomplish (1) and (2) but not getting any help in docs for (3) and (4). Could you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you mean set storage account name as key vault secret name and set storage access key as key vault secret value? Then get the access key from key vault to access azure storage?

Comment: @PamelaPeng that's part of it. KeyVault makes this claim "Key Vault manages storage account keys by periodically regenerating them in storage account and provides shared access signature tokens for delegated access to resources in your storage account" in this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/overview-storage-keys. I am looking for pointers to do that in C#.

Comment: Does this [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/key-vault-dotnet-managed-storage) help you?

Answer (score 0):

This post from Microsoft runs through the setup using PowerShell https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/overview-storage-keys-powershell.

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for a way to do it in C#. I did find ways (like the one you shared) to do it using PS and CLI.

Comment: Why do you want to do this via C#?

Comment: We need this automated and all our automation is in C# today.